# error installing sqlite3 Public Keyring not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

What is wrong? How can I install it?

PS C:\Users\luism> gem install sqlite3
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: mingw32: key "AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw64: key "AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: msys: key "AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
```

C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200718-41156-1cxbffc.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-config
--without-sqlite3-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: As an absolute Ruby Noob, I'm also stuck here when trying to initialize a new rails application. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4):

So it seems, a fresh installation of Ruby DevKit 2.6.6-1-x64 with MSYS2 is definitely broken by default.

I order to fix the PGP issue, start the mingw64 shell which can be found in the .**./Ruby26-x64/msys2/** directory and reset the pacman keystore by executing the following lines:

```
rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate msys2
```

Now you should be able to install rails without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @godsim solution is indeed working, but [msys2 website](https://www.msys2.org/news/) offers a bunch of possible other solutions, along with explantations. Here they are:

```
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig

pacman-key --verify msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig
```

==> Checking msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig... (detached)
gpg: Signature made Mon Jun 29 07:36:14 2020 CEST
gpg:                using DSA key AD351C50AE085775EB59333B5F92EFC1A47D45A1
gpg: Good signature from "Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) alexpux@gmail.com" [full]

```
pacman -U msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

This was not enough. Here is the line that worked for me:

```
pacman -U --config <(echo) msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

And finally, if that did not do the trick, @godsim's solution is to be tried.