# warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm very new to Ruby etc so please consider this in any replies :D

I'm trying to install Rails on my PC and I'm being hit with the above error.

There is another answer to this question ([error installing sqlite3 Public Keyring not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973797/error-installing-sqlite3-public-keyring-not-found)) but after working out how to install the mingw64 shell and resetting the pacman keystore, I'm still getting the same error.

Here's where it all went wrong:

```
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: ucrt64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: clang64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r
./siteconf20211116-149712-azfuy1.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

And here is the mkmf.log

```
"pkg-config --exists sqlite3"
package configuration for sqlite3 is not found
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <sqlite3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

And this is the version of sqlite3 on my computer

```
sqlite3 --version
3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03 fc82b73eaac8b36950e527f12c4b5dc1e147e6f4ad2217ae43ad82882a88alt2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this question. I'm also new to Ruby, and I am seeing a lot of the same errors regarding 'keyring not found', only mine are for the Puma gem. I don't have any advice to offer, just wanted to let you know you are not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: Please share the solution if you find one coz I am fcing the same issue 

Answer (score 1):

This answer worked for me

[error installing sqlite3 Public Keyring not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973797/error-installing-sqlite3-public-keyring-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I got below error

> warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
> error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: ucrt64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: clang64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
> error: keyring is not writable
> error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

I ran below command in mingw64(MSYS2 MINGW64 shell launcher). In mine, I found inside C:\Ruby31-x64\msys64.

> rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/

> pacman-key --init

> pacman-key --populate msys2

After this , I ran

> bundle install

in project path. It worked for me.