# Psych gem dependancy failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych

In my new windows pc i am setting up new rails application but while executing bundle install **Psych** dependancy is failed and i am stuck in this i have tried many solution but it didn't worked well if you know anything please share with me.
i tried this also [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973797/error-installing-sqlite3-public-keyring-not-found) solution but it also won't worked.

Ruby 3.2.3, Rails 7.1.3

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
warning: Public keyring not found; have you run 'pacman-key --init'?
error: clangarm64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: mingw64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: ucrt64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: clang32: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: clang64: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: msys: key "5F944B027F7FE2091985AA2EFA11531AA0AA7F57" is unknown
error: keyring is not writable
error: database 'clangarm64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'ucrt64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'clang32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'clang64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

Comment: "have you run 'pacman-key --init'?"

Comment: @tadman yes I did it.